# I am not able to style my input values as 'chips'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following input with for example two values

```
 <input id="input" type="text" />

let input = document.getElementById('input');
console.log(input);
input.value = 'John Peter';
```

I want this input values to appear as chips above my input but i can't find a way - how can i style the values inside my input. I need to do that because i have autocomplete where when i click on input additional window is opened where i can choose the options.

When i choose some option, it needs to appear as CHIP above the input.

Something like

https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples

So my chip styles looks like this

```css
.chip {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 18px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    font-weight: 600;
    min-height: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
    width: 60px;
}

.chip img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 -25px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.closebtn {
    color: #888;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    color:#ffffff;
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    opacity: .5;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
  color:#704e4e;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="chip">
  <span class="chip-text">Peter</span>
  <div class="closebtn"><span class="close-icon">&times;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can i make my values on the input `John and Peter` to appear as two `chips` on my input ?

Comment: You should use a other element. It won't be possible with just an html input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below accomplishes what you wanted. It creates 1 chip per name (the John and Peter) that you started with. Then attaches an on change listener to the input to take any new names and create a chip.

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function () {
  createChip(this.value);
  this.value = '';
});

['John', 'Peter'].forEach(createChip);

function createChip(val) {
  const el = document.createElement('li');
  el.innerText = val;
  document.getElementById('chips').appendChild(el);
}
```

```css
#chips {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#chips li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 18px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    font-weight: 600;
    min-height: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
    width: 60px;
}
#chips li::after {
  content: '\00D7';
  position:  relative;
  right: -25px;
  top: -10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  opacity: .5;
}
#chips li:hover::after {
    color: #000;
}
#input {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="chips"></ul>
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: @trstrand66 How can i specify width of the whole group ? I need border to be down - so the user can't notice that they are different things one ul and one input under. Also when there are more chips then the width, it should go under - not inline

Comment: @petar ok i made it so that the chips will wrap. Not sure what you want done with the border you will probably need to play with it. I made it disappear when not focused, but the on focus behavior differs by browser. You could slide it under the ul if you want it completely hidden.

Answer (score 0):

- Do not set your width for the chip, it won't be overflow with the content so add padding instead of width